# For which $p$ the sequence $x^n$ converges in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(I)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, solution-verification

I would like to know for which $p$ the sequence $u(n)=x^n$ converges in the Sobolev  space $W^{1,p}(I)$.

Is it true that converges only for $p=1$? I find out this looking for which $p$ the Sobolev norm of the sequence is finite. Am I right?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is $I$? The unit interval? But whatever $I$ is, noting that the polynomials are smooth, they are (should be) elements of $W^{1,p}(I)$. Since Sobolev spaces are Banach, in particular they are complete, to answer whether a sequence of elements converges you need to check whether the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Yes, $I$ is the unit intervall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \int_0^1 x^{pn} = \frac{1}{pn +1} x^{pn+1} |_0^1 <\infty
=\frac{1}{pn+1}$$
 and $$ \int_0^1 (n x^{n-1} )^p =
 \frac{n^p}{p(n-1)+1} $$ So for $1\leq p< \infty $, $x^n \in W^{1,p}$.

(1) But norm of $x^n$ goes to $\infty$ when $p> 1$. Hence in this
case it does not converge

(2) Let $p=1$. The norm of $x^n$ goes to $1$. Note that the limit is
$f(x)=0,\ x<1$ and $f(1)=1$, which is in $W^{1,p}(I)$. But $
\parallel f(x) \parallel_{1,p}= 0$. So $x^n$ does not converge in $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer..  But the second integral should be the interal of the derivate $n x^{n-1}$ for definition of Sobolev space...am I right?

Comment: Thank you for your reading. I fix it.